# Defining modules and using them immediately with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd

I'm writing some tests for an application which is using RequireJS. Because of how the application works, it expects to get some classes via calling `require`. So, for testing, I have some dummy classes, but I don't want to have to put them into individual files just for this test. I'd much prefer to just `define()` them manually inside my test file like so:

```
define('test/foo', function () {
    return "foo";
});

define('test/bar', function () {
    return "bar";
});

test("...", function () {
    MyApp.load("test/foo"); // <-- internally, it calls require('test/foo')
});
```

The issue here is that the evaluation of those modules is delayed until a script onload event is fired.

> From [require.js around line 1600](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L1600):
>
> ```
> //Always save off evaluating the def call until the script onload handler.
> //This allows multiple modules to be in a file without prematurely
> //tracing dependencies, and allows for anonymous module support,
> //where the module name is not known until the script onload event
> //occurs. If no context, use the global queue, and get it processed
> //in the onscript load callback.
> (context ? context.defQueue : globalDefQueue).push([name, deps, callback]);
> ```

Is there some way I can manually trigger the queue to be evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found so far is to asynchronously require the modules:

```
define("test/foo", function () { ... });
define("test/bar", function () { ... });

require(["test/foo"], function () {
    var foo = require('test/foo'),
        bar = require('test/bar');
    // continue with the tests..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

module definitions should be limited to one per file (see [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define)). i would guess that having multiple modules defined in a single file breaks the internal loading mechanisms, which rely on the script's load event to determine that it is ready while resolving dependencies.

even if it's just for testing, i'd recommend splitting those definitions into multiple files.

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: You can add more than one module per file (consider when you optimise + minify your whole application), you just have to give each module a specific name (see the first string argument to each `define` function in the OP).

Comment: Also, the modules are just for testing and they're **very** basic. A little more complicated than in the example above, but not much. Having each in its own file would be way too messy.

Comment: sure, i understand. but from what i can tell from the docs, the only case where you have a single file with multiple modules is after the optimization/build step occurs. to be honest, i'm not that familiar with requirejs, but i've used it on a couple of projects. the docs are pretty clear though: 'There should only be *one* module definition per file on disk. The modules can be grouped into optimized bundles by the optimization tool.' i would start there :)

Comment: yeah, the optimisation tool just puts them into one file, wrapped in define calls like that, but the modules are evaluated once that large script has finished loading. in my case, I need to make it evaluate it before then.