# requirejs - construct a module when it is defined, not when it is required

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a set of named requirejs modules with constructor-as-a-function.

```
define('myModule', [ 'import1', 'import2' ], function(i1, i2) {
    ...
});
```

I want to be able to

- attach modules to HTML in corect order *NOT USING* requirejs API via script tags
- attach and use modules *USING* requirejs API

Now, then I attaching a script with `define` call to a document, script is successfully loaded, but module is not getting to be defined, constructor is not called.

Is it a normal behaviour? Is there some workaround to fix this?

Comment: What do you need to define a module for when nothing uses (requires) it?

Comment: 1. I have some legacy code which knows nothing about modules and depends on file attachment instead. 2. I want to have some modules, containing global singleton objects. I want to attach them as a script in a head. I need modules here cause' they're depending on some other modules to work.

Comment: r.js with optimizer, might be a solid choice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> script is successfully loaded, but constructor is not called. Is it a normal behaviour?

Yes. They are only executed when needed, the `define` might be renamed as `register`. Also it might need to wait for its dependencies anyway.

> Is there some workaround to fix this?

If you want to execute it, just place a `require()` call for it ([not in the same file though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8880913)).

> I have some legacy code which knows nothing about modules and depends on file attachment instead.

While the script attachment does successfully load them (synchronously!), they will be executed asynchronously. You better would wrap the legacy code in `require`s as well (which shouldn't break anything).

Comment: Technically, where are no any limitations to execute modules synchronously if all dependencies are loaded (by the <script> tags previously placed in a document).

Comment: The linked question explains: "*the evaluation of those modules is delayed until a script `onload` event is fired*"